# RESTful Webservice - How to provide custom Classes' .xsd in xml output

Tags: java, web-services, rest, xsd

I've been searching like one and a half days but I can't find any useful answer...
(anyway, know I definetly know how to write webservices :D)

Here's my situation:
I am triying to setup a RESTful Webservices environment that provides returns an object names Greeting:

**Greeting.class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "greeting")
public class Greeting {

    private String message;
    private String name;

    public Greeting() {
    }

    public Greeting(String message, String name) {
        this.message = message;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The Webservice just returns an instance of Greeting... thats all!

**GreetingService.class**

```
@Path("sayHello")  
public class GreetingService {
      @Context
      private UriInfo context;
      public GreetingService() {
      }

      @GET
      @Produces("application/xml")
      public Greeting getJson(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
          return new Greeting(getGreeting(), name);
      }

      private String getGreeting() {
          return "Good " + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "Morning" : "Afternoon");
      }
}
```

And the result in the browser is this
**Browser**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<greeting>
    <message>Good Afternoon</message>
</greeting>
```

There is no information given about the detailed structure of Greeting.class :(
But other clients, who talk to the webservice might need it (yeah it's simple - BUT it's just an example!)

Do I have to configure anything? Maybe the application.wadl? I've no idea - was googling like I said - nearly two days :(
Please help me! 
BTW - I am using Netbeans, Java 7, JEE6 and Jersey

---

EDIT

Maybe I didn't ask correctly...
How can i automaticly provide the needed .xsd schema for Greeting?

Here's the application.wadl, which is provides at the moment...

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
<doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM"/>
    <resources base="http://localhost/iOSWebServices/resources/">
        <resource path="greeting">
            <method id="greet" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <method id="putXml" name="PUT">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </request>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

I found out, that there has to be a param "element" in the response representation - HOW can I set it there? Yeah I could use the WADL Plugin for Netbeans and type it in manually - but I have to add a schema reference for the element - in this case "Greeting" - and I still don't know how to set the namespace for the Greeting.class correctly :(

---

EDIT

I might have found what I was looking for..
http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2009/11/21/easy-restfull-jax-rs-webservices-and-extended-wadl-on-glassfish-v3-using-ant-/
This article explains what I wanted to know :)
Still have one exception in the last step when overriding  the WADL generation but I think, this is a version bug - gonna try to update jersey or to find a workaround!

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question/problem is?

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask correctly... How can i automaticly provide the needed .xsd schema for Greeting?

Comment: If you use NetBeans 7 I suggest to use the wizard, add getGreeting to the automatically-created GreetingFacadeREST class, and see the results: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: The result is abolutly what I don't want :(
There are no informations in the .xml like type of the meber etc..
I want to provide an additional .xsd for the clients who use the webservice, that they can rebuild the classes, which are returned by some web service methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found what I was looking for.. http://www.verborgh.be/articles/2009/11/21/easy-restfull-jax-rs-webservices-and-extended-wadl-on-glassfish-v3-using-ant-/ This article explains what I wanted to know :) Still have one exception in the last step when overriding the WADL generation but I think, this is a version bug - gonna try to update jersey or to find a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using NetBeans IDE, the following may help:

- http://netbeans.org/kb/67/websvc/wadl-zembly.html

Comment: Just so it's clear, a WADL document (potentially, and in practice definitely) includes the relevant XML schema as part of itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JAXB schema generation tool `schemagen` that can automatically generate an XSD for a java class.

See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html

Comment: I found that tool on my searches too - if I use it, I still don't know how to bind the .xsd to my java class or generated xml.
Can you tell me how?